# Joomla 3.2.1 Module Layout Override: Need to move category title subheading above grouped article titles

Tags: php, layout, joomla, overriding

I'm trying to create a mod_articles_category layout override for a Joomla 3.2.1 site.
I have 1 parent article category and about 10 child categories under it.

The default is to display the category title in parentheses beneath each article title, which looks crowded and repetitive.

What I'd like to do is display each category title subheading once above each child group of article titles.

So far, I've got it to display the category title (see comment below) but for some strange reason, it is displaying underneath the group of articles it relates to, instead of above it. How can I get it to move above each child group of article titles?

Thanks in advance for any tips.

======================

```
<ul class="category-module<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
<?php if ($grouped) : ?>
<?php foreach ($list as $group_name => $group) : ?>
<li>
<ul>    
    <!-- THIS IS THE CATEGORY TITLE SUBHEADING -->
<?php if ($item->displayCategoryTitle) :?>
<h3><?php echo $item->displayCategoryTitle; ?>
</h3>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php foreach ($group as $item) : ?>
<li>
<?php if ($params->get('link_titles') == 1) : ?>
<a class="mod-articles-category-title <?php echo $item->active; ?>" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">
<?php echo $item->title; ?>
</a>
<?php else : ?>
<?php echo $item->title; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($item->displayHits) : ?>
<span class="mod-articles-category-hits">
(<?php echo $item->displayHits; ?>)
</span>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($params->get('show_author')) :?>
<span class="mod-articles-category-writtenby">
<?php echo $item->displayAuthorName; ?>
</span>
<?php endif;?>

<?php if ($item->displayDate) : ?>
<span class="mod-articles-category-date"><?php echo $item->displayDate; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($params->get('show_introtext')) :?>
<p class="mod-articles-category-introtext">
<?php echo $item->displayIntrotext; ?>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($params->get('show_readmore')) :?>
<p class="mod-articles-category-readmore">
<a class="mod-articles-category-title <?php echo $item->active; ?>" href="<?php echo $item->link; ?>">
<?php if ($item->params->get('access-view') == false) :
echo JText::_('MOD_ARTICLES_CATEGORY_REGISTER_TO_READ_MORE');
elseif ($readmore = $item->alternative_readmore) :
echo $readmore;
echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', $item->title, $params->get('readmore_limit'));
if ($params->get('show_readmore_title', 0) != 0) :
echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', ($this->item->title), $params->get('readmore_limit'));
endif;
elseif ($params->get('show_readmore_title', 0) == 0) :
echo JText::sprintf('MOD_ARTICLES_CATEGORY_READ_MORE_TITLE');
else :
echo JText::_('MOD_ARTICLES_CATEGORY_READ_MORE');
echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', ($item->title), $params->get('readmore_limit'));
endif; ?>
</a>
</p>
<?php endif; ?>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<?php if ($item->displayCategoryTitle) :?>
<h3><?php echo $item->displayCategoryTitle; ?>
</h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

to

```
<h3><?php echo $group_name; ?></h3>
```